# Unity3D AI - Slow Down Approaching Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a good way to slow down a car AI I'm trying to develop for a racing game of mine. I'm wondering if anyone has programmed their own way to get this kind of AI to slow down when approaching objects. The idea is to mainly keep the AI from overshooting waypoints, but I'm willing to hear anyone's approach on this as I'm trying to figure out something that will work the best. I've been studying the Car AI Control from the Standard Assets in Unity, is this factor supposed to be the "cautiousness" you can set as a field variable?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be very bad design and sound stupid, but you can try to make invisible hit box around the car. Whenever you are not interacting with the hit box the enemies car speed will be reduced but when you hit the hit box than it will be increased (unless you go out of it).

Comment: I appreciate any answer! I'll give that a thought. Thanks.